# Where is the Ubuntu console on Windows10?

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-10-v1607

I updated my Windows 10 system to the 1607 "Anniversary Update" version and I can't find the Ubuntu Bash console.

So... Where is it?

Comment: I guess it's integrated into CMD/Powershell ?!

Comment: Not really an "Ubuntu" console - it's a bash shell session, which is available on all Unix/Linux platforms.

Comment: This may be pretty off-topic, but what is so infamous about it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

### To enable the bash shell from the Windows 10 Anniversary Update, you have to enable the feature `Windows Subsystem for Linux`

> **1. Go into the Control Panel and click *Turn Windows features on or off***
>   [image]
>
> **2. Then select the package *Windows Subsystem for Linux (Beta)*. It will go through the installation process and ask you to restart your computer.**
>   [image]
>
> **3. Once it's restarted, you can search for bash in the search bar.** 
>   [image]

Comment: And so I did. Now when I click on the `bash` command a window pops up for a milisecond and disappears. Any ideas how to debug it? When I type `bash` in cmd, I get `Unsupported console settings. In order to use this feature the legacy console mu
st be disabled.`. Is it somehow connected? Should I disable cmd? If so - how to do it?

Comment: @SzwornyDziąch what happens if you go into cmd and type bash? Does it prompt you to install Ubuntu?

Comment: That exact message appears. I tried disabling cmd as described here: https://www.maketecheasier.com/disable-command-prompt-windows/ and it's disabled now. However, that did not fix the problem. Btw, I had a short lag after clicking the `bash` command and so I could see that the same message appears.

Comment: @SzwornyDziąch re-enable cmd and disable cmd's legacy mode. To disable legacy mode, open cmd, then right click in the title bar and select properties. Then uncheck *use legacy console*. Here is a [pic](http://cdn.tweaks.com/img/article/commandprompt4.PNG)

Comment: @SzwornyDziąch no problem. Glad it's working for you. Have a *bash*ing good time! Heh, I made a funny.

Comment: You can also start bash from a PowerShell window, or from the icon in the start menu.

Answer (score 16):

I think you need to switch to developer mode as well.

[image]

Comment: That might be true. I've been in developer mode for a while, so I didn't know about that step. I'll have to turn it off and see if I can still access bash.

Comment: I confirmed that you do have to be in developer mode. Upon switching modes, I could no longer access the bash feature.

Comment: Yeah, I was prompted to do that when I did it too