# How to launch Bash on Ubuntu on Windows from third-party application?

Tags: bash, sublime-text-3, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've installed Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) in order to Bash on Ubuntu on Windows (in the following abbreviated to “Bash”.) In `cmd.exe` I can run `bash -c gcc --version` as well as I can use `cmd -k bash -c gcc --version` from the start menu. However, I noticed that I cannot run the same command from third-party applications, e.g. Sublime Text or Atom.

Consider the following build system for Sublime Text and, for the moment, ignore that fact that this wouldn't build anything:

```
{
  "cmd": [ "bash", "-c" "gcc", "--version" ],
  "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder}}",
  "selector" : "source.c"
}
```

Running the build command will result into  `Error: 0x80070057`. With legacy mode for `cmd.exe` enabled, the error reads `Unsupported console settings. In order to use this feature the legacy mode must be disabled.`

Among the other things I already tried to get it to work:

1. Using absolute paths to `bash.exe`, e.g. `%SystemRoot%\System32\bash.exe`
2. Run a Batch file in the build tool (content: `bash -c gcc --version`). Notably, the Batch file works when run from `cmd.exe`
3. Change the build command to `[ "cmd", "/k", "bash", "-c" "gcc", "--version"]`
4. Add `"shell": true` to my build file

At times  the error changes to ”[bash] is not recognized as an internal or external command”, even though `C:\Windows\System32` is in my path.

Is there a limitation that Bash can only be launched from `cmd.exe`? Are there any workarounds that would allow my to launch `batch` from Sublime Text?

Comment: Did you disable the legacy mode for cmd? You can see how to [disable legacy mode](http://superuser.com/questions/1108480/where-is-the-ubuntu-console-on-windows10/1108492#1108492) in the comments of the top answer.

Comment: Couple ideas... Try changing the `cmd` line to `"cmd": [ "cmd.exe", "-k", "bash -c gcc --version" ]`, and/or try adding `shell: true`.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I already tried these (as mentioned in the question). I edited my post and put my other attempts into a numbered list, which should be more legible.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can give a try to this solution.

[Using Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) from Sublime Text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40458143/4779598)

And no, it isn't necessary to replace `bash` with `bash.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your environment to test this, but I suggest replacing "bash" with "bash.exe". The Windows cmd.exe command requires the .exe suffix to execute the bash.exe command. The WSL command /usr/bin/bash is not the same command as the Windows command C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe.