# Access denied for newly created folder, unable to change permissions

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts, file-permissions, administrator, privileges

I just created a new folder: `C:\Projects\API` from the Command Prompt, using `mkdir API` from within the projects folder, after deleting an old folder of the same name, using: `RMDIR API /S`.

I then attempted to access the `API` folder from the same Command Prompt window, which resulted in the error:

`Access is denied.`

I closed down the Command Prompt window and reopened as administrator. Same issue.

I then opened Windows Explorer, right-clicked on the folder and selected Project Properties, followed by Security. The linked screen appeared:

[image: No permissions]

Showing no permissions. When I click the `Advanced` button, I see a screen:

[image: No permissions]

When I click either the `Change` button, to change ownership, or the `Continue` button, I get a third screen, saying:

```
You do not have permission to view or edit this object's permission settings.
```

Comment: Have you tried rebooting yet? Disk checks?

Comment: I haven't tried rebooting. I was hoping to avoid this if possible, as my computer is very slow to start and I have a lot of things I'm running at the same time. What sort of disk checks would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't uncommon to see people encounter issues with permissions when they create a new folder hierarchy at the root of the operating system partition.  Have you considered utilizing the `Public` profile folder hierarchy, instead?

That being said, it may be wise to delete the empty `API` folder and double-check the NTFS permissions on the `C:\Projects` folder before you attempt to recreate it.

Are you running Version 1607 (a.k.a. the Anniversary Update)?  If so, you can [utilize the Windows Subsystem for Linux bash shell](https://superuser.com/questions/1108480/where-is-the-ubuntu-console-on-windows10/1108492#1108492) to easily delete that folder.  Once you have the bash shell enabled, navigate to the location of the folder and use the command `rm -r [folder]` to delete it.

Comment: Windows Bash starts and quits immediately after starting, which is a known issue. Still looking into the problem and may raise a further issue. Standard Microsoft workaround does nothing.

Comment: That is unfortunate, and definitely an issue that I haven't encountered first-hand just yet.  If necessary, you can always reboot your computer using a Linux Live distro image and delete the folder(s) without being hampered by Windows permissions.

Comment: After a second restart trying to get Windows Bash to work, I remembered I have Git Bash on my computer. Upon navigating to the file area in Git Bash I found the folder has disappeared: it appears during the process of the second restart the system has cleared the folder away itself. I have accepted your answer as it has been helpful in solving the problem, and clued me in as to what to do next time if the same issue reoccurs.

Comment: Glad to hear that everything is back to normal.